# Many records in mysql suddenly dissapear/missing

Tags: php, mysql

I have a wierd case. Suddenly some records (so many records) in one of the table are missing.. first, I tought it is caused by bug in my PHP script. But, I checked it, there's no `DELETE` operation in my script, only `UPDATE`. Does anyone knows what happen with my MySql?

Comment: Perhaps table crashed. Try to repair it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html

Comment: Is that a wordpress site??  or plain php website?

Comment: Or undeploy your web application and check.. to know whether the problem is in your code or someware else..

Comment: Thanks for the info I'll try it. But I still confuse.. it is only affect one of my table and all the data is gone except last inserted data. In this table i had data from 2010 until 2012. Suddenly, all the data is gone except data that inserted in June 2012

Comment: It is plain php website. The script just for insert and update operation. No delete operation..

Comment: I think because of auto increment id.
visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692068/will-mysql-reuse-deleted-ids-when-auto-increment-is-applied

Answer (score 2):

I too think Some one might have executed SQL Injection by deleting rows or dropping tables

Comment: It is possible that a bug in my script cause it and not because SQL injection? I just want to make sure, is UPDATE operation can delete a record?

Comment: Can you give us some details of the database layout and the queries you use?

Comment: Exactly Please provide us with some details

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you or someone who have access, restored database from dump?

Answer (score 1):

See here:
http://owasp.com/index.php/SQL_Injection

Some stuff to check: 
If you use something like phpMyAdmin, make sure nobody can access it from outside.

If you use stored procedures verify them as well, some might delete. External applications might delete stuff from your database so strictly control who has privileges.

Also you can make sure you log all your operations and you can keep backups using the mysqldump command that you can compare daily:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Mihai