# adding new record to the AUTO_INCREMENT column

Tags: mysql, xampp

I created an AUTO_INCREMENT column(id) primary key. When a record is deleted from the table and a new record is added,the id's value automatically gets set to 1 more than the value of previous id.

i want the new record to take the previously left space created by the old deleted id instead of it occupying a new space.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692068/will-mysql-reuse-deleted-ids-when-auto-increment-is-applied

Comment: Why?  The purpose of an auto-incremented primary key is to uniquely identify each row.  Gaps should not be an issue.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214141/mysql-auto-increment-after-delete